# How to truncate NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I looked at the string formatting documents but couldn't figure out exactly how to do this.

Lets say I have a sting like this

`@"(01–05) Operations on the nervous system"`

I want to create 2 strings from this like so:

`@"01-05"` and `@"Operations on the nervous system"`

How can I do this?

Here are the docs I looked at: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html

Comment: I think you are over thinking it.  Just look at the NSString docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot. It might be off a bit, I havent checked for typos. But you can mess around with it now that you get the idea.

```
NSString * sourceString = @"(01–05) Operations on the nervous system";

NSString *string1 = [sourceString substringToIndex:6];
string1 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];

//string1 = 01-05

NSString *string2 =[sourceString substringFromIndex:7];

//string2 = Operations on the nervous system
```

Comment: You're hard coding the length of the first substring.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I already know that! I gave him exactly what he was looking for. Did he ask for a dynamic way? No - so you probably shouldn't downvote if that was you.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the first substring contained by the characters "(" and ")" and anything after that I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
NSString *original = @"(01–05) Operations on the nervous system";
NSString *firstPart = [NSString string];
NSString *secondPart = [NSString string];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:original];

[scanner scanUpToString:@"(" intoString:NULL];           // find first "("
if (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanString:@"(" intoString:NULL];           // consume "("
    [scanner scanUpToString:@")" intoString:&firstPart]; // store characters up to the next ")"
    if (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
        [scanner scanString:@")" intoString:NULL];       // consume ")"

        // grab the rest of the string
        secondPart = [[scanner string] substringFromIndex:[scanner scanLocation]];
    }
}
```

Of course the secondPart string will still have spaces and whatnot at the front of it, to get rid of those you can do something along the lines of:

```
secondPart = [secondPart stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
```

The advantage of using NSScanner is that you don't have to hard-code the start and end of the firstPart substring.

Answer (score 1):

NSString *theFirstStringSubString = [NSString substringFromIndex:1];

NSString *theFirstStringSecondSubstring = [theFirstStringSubString substringToIndex:6];

Now theFirstStringSecondSubstring is 01-05
same thing for the other but at different indexes. Please note that these are strings that are autoreleased. If you want to keep them, retain it.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I'm trying to apply it to a UITableView cell's text from a plist.  This is giving me `08–16) Operations on the eye` for `theFirstStringSubString ` and `08–16)` for the `theFirstStringSecondSubstring`.

Comment: o my bad its not 6 is 5. Like I said thats the first one. the other one is just a matter of counting the index. If the string varies then

NSString *theFirstStringSubString = [originalString substringFromIndex:8];

NSString *theFirstStringSecondSubstring = [theFirstStringSubString substringToIndex:[originalString length]-1];